# Perfomance tool for mono application

Tags: c#, performance, mono

I've some questions about mono application development.

I'm developping a Monotouch application for IOS device.

I develop with Monodevelopp IDE on macOSX environment so I can't use ressource monitor .

Do you know if a tool exists like "performance explorer" on visual studio 2010, to measure precisely a mono application performance?

I already tested "Mono profile" and "Instruments" but they are not as powerful.

I need to evaluate the most expensive functions in my app to try to improve my app's performance.

If you have any idea you're welcome.

Comment: You can use resource monitor

Comment: Sorry I missed some precision in my question . I'm developping a Monotouch application for IOS device. I develop with Monodevelopp IDE on macOSX environment so I can't use ressource monitor .

Comment: Did you try Project -> Profile Mono?